# undefined method `add' for #<List:0xea5520> (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

I am making myself a task list in Ruby and was getting this error

```
You have created a new list
todo.rb:13:in `<class:List>': undefined method `add' for #<List:0xea5520>     (NoMethodError)
from todo.rb:9:in `<main>'
```

Running my code

```
class Task
   attr_accessor :description

   def initialize(description)
       @description = description
   end
end

class List
    def initialize(all_tasks)
        @all_tasks = []
        attr_accessor :all_tasks
    end
    def add(task)
            all_tasks << task
    end
    if __FILE__ == $0
        my_list = List.new
        puts 'You have created a new list'
        add(Task.new('Make tutorial video'))
        puts 'Added sample task to Todo List'
    end
end
```

I changed it with people's suggestions but I'm getting this one now instead

```
todo.rb:10:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)
    from todo.rb:19:in `new'
    from todo.rb:19:in `<class:List>'
    from todo.rb:9:in `<main>'
```

I am passing in an argument aren't I?

Answer (score 0):

Try it without object of  "my_list" like this

> `add(Task.new('Make tutorial video'))`

Comment: Now it says "todo2.rb:13:in `<class:List>': undefined method `add' for List:Class (NoMethodError)
        from todo2.rb:9:in `<main>'"

Comment: hmmm. put add method under private

Comment: That helped. There were a few other errors I could fix myself but now I have a whole new one :(.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to do that

```
def add(task)  
  all_tasks << task
end
```

Comment: Gives me:

todo.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting ')'
        def initialize(:description)
                        ^
todo.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following on irb and it worked.

```
class Task
  attr_accessor :description

  def initialize(description)
    @description = description
  end
end

class List
  attr_accessor :all_tasks

  def initialize(all_tasks)
    @all_tasks = []
  end

  def add(task)
    all_tasks << task
  end

  my_list = List.new([1,2])
  puts 'You have created a new list'
  my_list.add(Task.new('Make tutorial video'))
  puts 'Added sample task to Todo List'
end
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me what I was doing wrong so I know for next time?

Comment: Your initialize has argument so you need to pass argument while creating an object of class. You have written add method under private.

Comment: Why did  you put [1,2] in the array?

Comment: [awais](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2779976/awais-shafqat) told me to put add method under private, I am so confused!

Comment: I have put array because in `add` method you have written `all_tasks << task`

Comment: but my array is for tasks and you put numbers though

Comment: You can change it as per your requirement, can you provide me some example of your tasks.?

Comment: my tasks are to make a voiceover for a video and to go to teater group and to clean my house and talk to my house helper